# please can anyone help me to find out the mistake or error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I have done client and server sign-in & sign-up for my project after fetching register API from the frontend it is showing "please fill all fields"  error which i was provide the validation. I have filled all the fields properly but it is showing the error again and again.

****Here my backend code ****

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config({ path: "../config.env" });
const User = require("../models/UserModel");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const userCntrl = {
  userregsiter: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { role, username, email, mobile, password, confirmpassword } =
        req.body;


      if (
        !role ||  !username || !email || !mobile ||  !password || !confirmpassword
      ) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "**please fill all the fields**" });
      }

      if (!validateEmail(email)) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "**invalid email check again**" });
      }

      const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });

      if (existingUser) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "**user already have exits**" });
      }

      if (password.length < 6) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ error: "**password  must be least 06 character**" });
      }

        // if (password !== confirmpassword) {
        //   return res.status(400).json({ error: "**passsword do not match**" });
        // }

      const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

      console.log(passwordHash);

      const newUser = new User({
        role,
        username,
        email,
        mobile,
        password: passwordHash,
        confirmpassword: passwordHash,
      });

      console.log(newUser);
      const saveUser = await newUser.save();

      console.log(saveUser);

      res.status(200).json({ msg: "Register succusfully" });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return res.status(500).json({ error });
      
    }
  },

  protected: (req, res) => {
    res.json({ msg: "auth is working " });
  },

  userlogin: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { email, password } = req.body;
      if (!email || !password) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ error: "**please fill email and password**" });
      }

      const user = await User.findOne({ email });

      if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "**This email does not exist**" });
      }

      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

      if (!isMatch || !email) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ error: "** Invalid email or password**" });
      }

      const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY);

      res.json({ token });

      //  res.json({ msg: "Login success!" });
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(500).json({ error });
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
};

function validateEmail(email) {
  const re =
    /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}

module.exports = userCntrl;
```

**Here my frontend code**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./UserRegister.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ing from "../assets/ing.png";
import { message } from "antd";
const UserRegister = () => {
  const [role, setRole] = useState("");
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [mobile, setMobile] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [confrimpassword, setConfrimpassword] = useState("");

  console.log({
    role,
    username,
    email,
    mobile,
    password,
    confrimpassword,
  });
  const fetchRegister = () => {
    fetch("/api/user/userregsiter", {
      method: "post",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        role,
        username,
        email,
        mobile,
        password,
        confrimpassword,
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.msg) {
          message.success(data.msg);
        } else {
          message.error(data.error);
        }
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="body_body">
      <div className="signup-container">
        <div className="welcome-img">
          <img src={ing} alt="welcome image" height="350px" width="450px" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-container">
          <h2>Create your Account Today ! </h2>

          <p class="title">Sign Up</p>

          <div class="signup-form">
            <div class="form-item selector">
              <span class="item-indicator"></span>
              <label className="select_label" for="role">
                Choose your role
              </label>
              <select
                id="role"
                className="role_select"
                value={role}
                onChange={(e) => setRole(e.target.value)}
              >
                <option value="Student">Student</option>
                <option value="Company">Company</option>
                <option value="Mentor">Mentor</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-item fullname">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Please enter your username "
                value={username}
                onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
              />
              <span class="item-indicator"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-item email">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter your email"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
              <span class="item-indicator"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-item confirm-password">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder=" Enter Mobile No"
                name="mobile"
                value={mobile}
                onChange={(e) => setMobile(e.target.value)}
              />
              <span class="item-indicator"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-item password">
              <input
                type="password"
                placeholder="Enter Password"
                name="password"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
              <span class="item-indicator"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-item confirm-password">
              <input
                type="password"
                name="Confirmpassword"
                placeholder="Enter Confirm Password"
                value={confrimpassword}
                onChange={(e) => setConfrimpassword(e.target.value)}
              />
              <span class="item-indicator"></span>
            </div>

            <p class="login">
              Already have an account?
              <Link to="login">Login</Link>
            </p>
            <div class="actions">
              <button type="submit" onClick={() => fetchRegister()}>
                Sign Up
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserRegister;
```

Comment: can you provide an example of the json that you are sending?

Comment: in the postman, it is working perfectly, but in the frontend, it is showing the error message.                                                                                                                         
      {
    "role":"company",
    "username":"demeoname",
    "email":"demeoname@gmail.com",
    "mobile":"demonumber",
    "password":"1$34567",
    "confirmpassword":"1$34567"
}

Comment: in your frontend code inside your fetchRegister() you have a typo.
fetch("/api/user/userregsiter") I believe it should be /api/user/userregister. could this be it?

Comment: I have changed the route  it is showing the same validation error  once I comment the    if (
        !role ||  !username || !email || !mobile ||  !password || !confirmpassword
      ) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "**please fill all the fields**" });
      }                                                                                                                                            this codes it is working in the frontend site

Comment: you have another typo in your frontend JSON.stringify you have confrimpassword when it should be confirmpassword. it could be slipping up your validation.

Comment: no problem, please if I answered your problem accept the answer that I have provided. Thanks 

Comment: The title is vague enough to make the question off-topic, I think. Titles should be a succinct description of the problem at hand, to help future readers find it and understand it.

Comment: Ah, it is a "typo" answer anyway.

Comment: use elseif or switch, instead of multiple ifs in your backend code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your JSON.stringify() on your frontend code.

```
body: JSON.stringify({
        role,
        username,
        email,
        mobile,
        password,
        confrimpassword,
      }),
```

You have misspelled confirmpassword.

Comment: Please don't answer "typo" questions - they are usually closed & deleted anyway.